# Save object of type <class 'list'> to disk

Tags: python, list, object, variables, pickle

I am newbie in Python and I am trying to save some data in the disk by using pickle but I am not being able to do so. The data type is **class 'list'** and has a couple of elements. I have also tried with f.write() by using a for loop but I have no success.

I do not really know if the thing I want to save is a variable or an object but it has **class 'list'** type. The thing is named myapp.vk and has the form of a list like this [417, [118]]. In other words, if I print myapp.vk, the result is something like this [417, [118]]. Tried with pickle and with f.write() but I have not succeeded. I assume it is due to the type of the data (do not know if myapp.vk is an object or a variable and do not know how to handle it).

WITH PICKLE:

```
with open(file, "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(myapp.vk, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

WITH WRITE:

```
with open(file, 'w') as file:
    file.write('[')
    for i in range(len(myapp.vk)):
        file.write(dumps(myapp.vk[i]))
    file.write(']'
```

I would like to know how to handle such information and how to save it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by using JSON.

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(myapp.vk, f)
```